# Drop char code from start of string in a whole column

Tags: r, regex, string

Trying to drop a euro character code from the start of a column. Column was ingested as character by `readr`, but I need to convert to integers

```
data$price[1:3]

[1] "\u0080343,000.00" "\u0080185,000.00" "\u0080438,500.00"
```

so need to get rid of `\u0080` from the start (and , and . but we'll deal with those later)

tried:

```
data$price <- sub("\u0080", "", data$price)
-- no change(!!!)

data$price <- substr(data$price, 7, 100)
-- invalid multibyte string, element 1 (???)
```

I'd like to get to:

```
343000, 185000, 438500
```

But not sure how to get there. Any wisdom would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can tell R to use the exact text rather than regular expressions by using the `fixed = TRUE` option.

```
price <- c("\u0080343,000.00", "\u0080185,000.00", "\u0080438,500.00")

sub("\u0080", "", price, fixed = TRUE)

[1] "343,000.00" "185,000.00" "438,500.00"
```

To remove the comma and convert to an integer, you can use `gsub`.

```
as.integer(gsub(",", "", sub("\u0080", "", price, fixed = TRUE)))

[1] 343000 185000 438500
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for replacements, I'm now just getting a UTF-8 formatting error. So I'll keep searching around for answers to that one..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
gsub("[^ -~]+", "", price)
"343,000.00" "185,000.00" "438,500.00"
```

Explanation:

The Euro sign is a non-ASCII character. So to get rid of it in the values in `price` we define a character class of ASCII characters in `[ -~]`; by negating the class through the caret `^` we match non-ASCII characters (such as €). This pattern is matched in `gsub`and replaced by `""`, i.e., nothing.
To convert to integer, proceed as in @Adam's answer. To convert to numeric, you can do this:

```
as.numeric(gsub(",", "", gsub("[^ -~]+", "", price)))
```

Comment: Glad it helped you! Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick in the left upper corner of the answer!